# Can ViewPager be used inside a custom Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I am trying to use a ViewPager inside a custom Dialog... is it possible to use ? Am using the v4 support library "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" inside the custom dialog xml.

When I run the application the ViewPager object throws a nullpointerexception..

please help

My custom dialog xml file is as follows :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:tag="test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I have added 5 pages in viewpager which I have added using PagerAdapter...

The below code is present in the main activity onCreate() method :

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
Window window = d.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
d.setTitle("Dialog");
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

final MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
myPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

here my pager is returning null... and when i run the code it shows nullpointerexception

Comment: Kindly go through my video for Pager in Dialog **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJG5ZuZtPKY**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having your ViewPager in `R.layout.dialog`, then you have to provide the reference of your view object when you Initialize it.  Change your code like this,

```
final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager)d. findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
```

Add the Object of Dialog "d" as I have done here and check.

Comment: thanks a lot... I wasn't using the object of Dialog to get the viewpager